# How to show progress when swiping between fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I have an activity with pager adapter which contains some fragments. I've also created a progressBar (horizontal) on the top of the activity. I need that the bar would show the progress when I am swiping through the fragments. For example, it should be grey when I am in the first fragment then gradually grow when I swipe through the fragments and fully green when I am in the last fragment.

**mainActivity.java**

```
public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_adapter);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private  void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));
        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I've found a very simple answer. This is what I did:

```
  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
          //This is because progress is 0 at the start of the program
          progress++;
          ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progress.setProgress(position++);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `OnPageChangeListener` to you `ViewPager` in your Activity like this

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
       // Update the progress bar according to pos
       // Also note that you reach the end when pos == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1
       // and that pos starts at 0 - this is the first fragment
    }

});
```

Comment: What should I write after onPageSelected?

Comment: You should be changing the color of your progress bar. Make an array of int colors or color res IDs and get the color for the position and set it to the peogress bar. Can you do it?

Comment: Not really. But I'll try.